# Fell off an island in the end! Help!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

What do you do if you fall off an island in the end in creative? I fell off one and now I can't find any island!

Answer (score 8):

You're already in creative mode, so you're in luck! The easiest way to get un-lost in the End when in creative mode is to use the [teleport command](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#tp) to teleport yourself back to the central island. It happens to be at map coordinates *0,0*, which makes it relatively easy to locate.

Hit <kbd>t</kbd> to open the chat and enter this:

```
/tp 0 100 0
```

and press <kbd>enter</kbd>. You will be teleported to high above the central island of the End.